# Running the Tcl interpreter in a Windows service

Tags: c++, windows, tcl

would anyone have experience running the Tcl interpreter in a Windows service?

I modified an existing C++ program that runs as a Windows service. The modification I made is to create a Tcl interpreter in the program and call Tcl procedures located in external files. The program works fine when run interactively, but fails with messages like "cannot find channel named sock424" when run as a service.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are plenty of wrappers for Tcl as a service.  Start with http://wiki.tcl.tk/1795 on the Tcl wiki.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The scenario in the wrappers at the link you provided is to run the Tcl interpreter itself as a Windows service. But in my case the service already exists as a C++ program. What I'm trying do is to add a Tcl interpreter in the program to execute external Tcl scripts. Is it possible that the service is interfering with the Tcl event loop?

Comment: If you look at the source code for the wrappers they should show you how to go about creating a Tcl interpreter within a service, try http://www.sensus.org/tcl/index.htm for tclsvc.  Also if you post the code you've got so far it would help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Ok I'll write a simplified version that reproduces the problem and I'll post it. I looked at the code of tclsvc. The main loop looks like this: `while (stopRequested == 0) {Tcl_DoOneEvent(TCL_ALL_EVENTS);}`. It seems to confirm what I feared: the Tcl event loop has to be called explicitely. I don't see how I can do that in my case without touching the existing C++ service code.

Comment: You should edit your question to put more of these pieces of information in; they'll make it more specific and a much better question.

Comment: @DonalFellows Thanks for the advice. I'll try something: I'll run the interpreter in a separate thread within the Windows service. It should isolate the Tcl event loop from the service loop. I'll add a comment when I'm done.

Comment: I was a bit in a rush to make this work. The workaround was to start an external interpreter with a command pipeline. The program running in a Windows service calls a `proc` in the script that spawns an external interpreter with `open |`. The Tcl script in the main program then communicates with the external interpreter with blocking `puts` and `gets`, so that the Tcl interpreter in the main program doesn't have to go in the event loop. I haven't had time yet to write a program that demonstrates the original problem. I will when I have a chance. Thanks for the help.